# How can I make my program print how many times specific words are shown on a website?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am very very new to python and I've gotten this program to list the amount of times a word is shown from a page. Now I want it to show how many times separate two words, or three, or four are shown. I've tried adding commas to my variables but it makes the program have an error. What should I do?

```
import requests


def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url).text
    return r.count(the_word)


def main():
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMC_Theatres'
    word = ('movie')
    x = 0
    count = count_words(url, word)
    x = x + count
    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} occurrences of word: {}'.format(url, count, word))
    print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Call `count_words` once for each word you want to count.  Or rewrite `count_words` to be able to count multiple words.

Comment: Assuming that GET returns something in its *text* attribute (you can't be sure because you don't check) then your results are likely to be ambiguous. The Python string function *count()* will reveal the number of times a particular sequence of characters occurs. So, for example, 'garage'.count('age') == 1. Furthermore, the text attribute will contain the entire HTML from that page. That's almost certainly not what you want

Comment: I don't know why you're getting down votes but you might want to post what errors you get next time.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, this is my first day. I'll be sure to post my errors next time I have a question

Comment: OK. Both answers below work for me.  Feel free to up-vote them or mark them as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to iterate over the list of words you wants to counts. For example:

```
def main():
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMC_Theatres'
    x = 0
    words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
    for word in words:
        count = count_words(url, word)
        x = x + count
        print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} occurrences of word: {}'.format(url, count, word))
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary "word_dict" with the words you would like to find as the "keys" and set the values to 0.  Then pass the dictionary (not the word) to your count_words function.  Modify your count_words function to set the new value.

```
import requests

def count_words(url, word_dict):
    r = requests.get(url).text
    for word in word_dict:
        word_dict[word] = r.count(word)
    return word_dict


def main():
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMC_Theatres'
    #word = 'movie'
    word_dict = {'movie':0, 'Projectors':0,'Disney':0,'States':0}
 
    count_dict = count_words(url, word_dict)
    for word in count_dict:
        print(f'Url: {url} contains {count_dict[word]} occurrences of word: {word}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see more on dictionaries here - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
Look around on how to iterate through dictionaries and lists.
Welcome and good luck.